# Google Map Version

Tags: google-maps

Hi I am Using Google Map Version 2 in my asp.net web application. now my problem is the in map area GMAPEZ is displaying and nothing else and i have no error in my XML File with valid Google Map key. What could be the problem

Comment: Without seeing the live site, it's impossible to make suggestions. I'd suggest posting the site so we can review it. Also, consider switching to maps api v3, since v2 is deprecated and liable to be shut off next year.

Comment: hi please find the live site http://online.smude.edu.in/SMUDELCLocator/

Answer (score 0):

You declare your map type as G_MAP_TYPE on line 766 of gmapez-2.js.

```
  var mapType = G_MAP_TYPE;
```

You probably want to do one of the standard map types:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/introduction#CommonMapTypes

I found this in a few seconds using the Chrome Developer Tools. Here's a good reference so you can do the same:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=nb4gvrNrDWw

Comment: Can i Download gmapez-2.js File which is using V3 Google Map

Comment: I don't know what gmapez-2.js is, you could just use the google Maps API directly: https://developers.google.com/maps/  It's very simple.